# How to configure git to use meld for diff & merge

Tags: windows, git, meld, difftool

Running Windows 11.
Trying to configure `meld` as a diff/merge tool used with git the same way I'm using it under Linux.

Meld launches OK via `git difftool --dir-diff`, but looks like it fails to read/write into/from the temporary locations:

```
There was a problem opening the file “C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Temp\git-difftool.a09536\left”.
Error opening file C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Temp\git-difftool.a09537\left: No such file or directory
```

Note this error is shown in meld's own UI. Similar error for the right-hand pane.

Relevant parts of `C:\Users\myusername\.gitconfig`:

```
[merge]
    tool = meld_conf
    conflictstyle = diff3
    prompt = false
[mergetool "meld_conf"]
    cmd = meld --auto-merge $LOCAL $BASE $REMOTE --output $MERGED --diff $LOCAL $BASE --diff $BASE $REMOTE
[difftool]
    prompt = true
[diff]
    tool = meld
    renames = true
    colorMoved = default
    indentHeuristic = true
```

```
$ git --version
git version 2.41.0.windows.1
```

Meld `3.22.0`, installed via [chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/meld).

Any input?

Comment: I tested latest git and Meld on Windows now and it worked fine, try upgrading if still an issue.

Comment: @Destroy666 my question states using v `3.22.0`, which is the latest stable version as of right now. Which meld and git settings did you use that worked for you?